# Piping output of a QIODevice to a QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qt4, qtextedit, qprocess

How to I make the output of a `QIODevice` (`QProcess`, specifically) go into a `QTextEdit` in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the [QProcess::readyRead](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal to a slot that then reads from the QProcess using [QProcess::readAllStandardOutput](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) and writes the text to the QTextEdit with [QTextEdit::append](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtextedit.html#append).

Answer (score 0):

Write own class!

Header:

```
class MyProcess : public QProcess
{
  Q_OBJECT
...
protected:
  virtual qint64 readData( char * data, qint64 maxlen );
...
};
```

Source:

```
qint64 MyProcess::readData( char * data, qint64 maxlen )
{
  qint64 return_value = QProcess::readData(data,maxlen);
  QString str(QByteArray(data,return_value));
  // write out to QTextEdit
  return return_value;
}
```

Comment: Judge Maygarden's answer seems much simpler to implement and makes more sense. (I wasn't the one who down-voted, though)

Comment: @mtk358: it is true. On other hand it could be not real time. If the `connect` choose queued connection, the reaction won't be real time. [Link.](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)