# nube: stdio to QTextedit

Tags: qt, qt4

I've read lots of similar threads to this one but im not such a great programmer that i can make sense of it all. Im using qtcreator to make life simple and want to maka a program that can trigger another process, monitor its stdout and then kill it if necessary.

What I assume i want to do is create a QTextedit in the designer and plug a signal into it that updates the contained text whenever the stream updates, so far so good, but thats where i get fuzzy. My initial thought was to create a subclass of QObject that starts the process as a QProcess and whenever the stdout updates the QObject and appends new data to the QTextedit box.

So my program structure would run like this:

on button press create new QObject derived class.

The QObject derived class constructor starts a QProcess and connects the readyReadStdout() signal to the derived qObject class slot.

When the derived QObject is triggered it takes readyReadStdout() and appends any new data to the QTetEdit box.

on button press, call the derived QObject destructor and which kills the process.

Has anybody done something similar? Like i say ive read similar posts but sometimes it takes asking a question in your own words to be able to understand it

Thanks everyone (also my forst post, woo:)

---

Ok so heres my update:

I have added an instance of QProcess class (named proc) to my mainWindow class and also new instance of a QObject derived class (named procLog) to which I added a slot. I want this slot to take the readyReadStandardOutput() signal as a trigger to call readAllStandardOutput() and emit the new line to a new signal in procLog, I'm having trouble connecting the QProcess slot to the QObject derived class. heres what I'm trying:

```
connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput ()), procLog, SLOT(logReady()));
```

I get, error: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::readyReadStandardOutput () to (null)::logReady()

Do you know why this is. Aslo is there a way to add code blocks to text in the comments?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping output of a QIODevice to a QTextEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587504/piping-output-of-a-qiodevice-to-a-qtextedit)

Comment: yes, this is a good aproach, although you might not need a separate QObject-derived class for it. Please read the related questions (on the right of this page), this has been asked and done a lot.

Comment: iv never had such a quick response! ill get reading and see how far i get, really appreciate it!

Comment: could i have a hand writing the implementation of the post that Mat linked to:

"Connect the QProcess::readyRead signal to a slot that then reads from the QProcess using QProcess::readAllStandardOutput and writes the text to the QTextEdit with QTextEdit::append."

for a start where should i start the QProcess? in the main loop?

(p.s. i cant get used to return submitting the comment rather thad adding a new line, hence the useless comments:)

(also should i add questions like this in the comments or by clicking 'answer your question'?)

Comment: read the Qt signals & slots documentation, and the examples. Also read the QProcess docs. They're all pretty good. If you have a specific problem, post a question with what exact problem you're having), but you have to show what you've managed to code so far. So go read the docs and practice. It's fun, you'll see :-)

Comment: one thing i cant understand do you have to write an implementation of a signal? or do you just define it and use emit to write to it? thanks! (p.s. im reading the docs now)

Comment: slots are functions, they have code. signals are not functions, they don't have code. they are just emitted.